# Application Pool recycle issue

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

I have one problem which I am not able to understand.

There are some unhandled exception in my asp.net application which I believe setting some of static variable in my class to null.

I believe this is because unhandled exception is recycling the application pool.

```
If I use Apllication_Error in global.asax , will that stop recycling of app pool?
```

Comment: Provide more information: How do you log your errors? Do your write anything in FileSystem? which Exception does cause this problem?

Comment: I am not doing anything in application_error. It's just some exception which I am not handling anywhere.

Comment: do you use some error logger such as Log4Net

Comment: No, I am not using log4net.

Answer (score 0):

> If I use Application_Error in global.asax , will that stop recycling
>   of app pool?

No, Application_Error might or might not even be reached, if Application Pool recycles due to hard crash.

It seems that you do not have any logging framework in your application. One thing you can do at this point is to see the errors in Event Viewer.

*For example,*

[image]

***FYI***: To view friendly error messages, you might want to add error logging to your application such as NLog, Log4Net or Elmah.

Comment: I am using HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException(); and sending this error to admin, will that stop app pool recycle? @Win

Comment: By checking eventviewer I came to know that there is some unhandled exception.

Comment: You cannot stop application pool recycle caused by application crash. Normally, it does not recycle unless you explicitly configure to recycle or the code has serious bug.